# jsTree: with lazy loading the plugin "dnd" is not working

Tags: jstree, jstree-dnd

I'm using jsTree (latest version) in my web app. I have a lot of nodes to display in the tree, so I am using lazy loading otherwise I would run into a time out.
When the tree is loaded, the user can pick values from a second tree and move them into the lazy loaded tree (jsTree plugin "dnd"). Both tree have the jsTree plugin "dnd" installed. But I can not drop a element into the lazy loaded tree, when I try to do so the node to be dropped is having an icon with a red cross (indication: not allowed here).

This is the code for the lazy loaded tree:

```
$('#target_tree').jstree({
  'core' : {
    'data' : {
      "url" : "get_current_hierachy",
      "data" : function (node) {
        return {'p_parent_id': node.id};
      },
      "dataType": "json",
      "check_callback": true
    }
  },
  "plugins" : ["dnd"]
});
```

When I load some data in the first tree without the lazy loading, the drag'n'drop is working as expected.
When I load data in the first tree with lazy loading, the drag'n'drop is not working any more.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#target_tree').jstree({

        'core': {
            'data': {

                "url": function (node) {
                    var url;
                    if (node.id == '#') {
                        url = "getRootNode";
                    } else {
                        var id = $(node).data("id");
                        url = "getChildNode?nodeid=" + id;
                    }
                    return url;
                },
                "data": function (node) {
                    return { "id": node.id };
                },
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": "json",
                "contentType": "application/json charset=utf-8",
            },
            'check_callback': true,
        },
        "plugins": ["dnd"]

    });
});
```

I think you need to prepare url

Comment: No, the lazy loading is working perfectly! The decision if it is a root node or a child node is done in the procedure "get_current_hierachy" itself.

As I described, the "dnd" plugin is not working any more, I cannot move nodes from one tree into the other tree.